# Regex match string that starts with but does not include in CSV data

Tags: java, regex

I have data with the following variations. It is in CSV format.

```
1,"aaaaaaaaaa,,,,11111
2,"bbbbbb,bbbbbbb",,,,2222222
3,ccccccccc",,,,3333333333
```

How do I write a regex that can only match `"aaaaaaaaaa` or `ccccccccc"` but ignore `"bbbbbb,bbbbbbb"`?

I tried with `("[a-z]+?,)(?!("[a-z0-9,]+?",))` but `"bbbbbb,bbbbbbb"` is also matched.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to achieve? Exclude Strings containg 'b' characters? Exclude Strings that all characters are 'b'?

Comment: What about two regular expressions? One for finding all strings A-Z and a next one for excluding B?

Comment: Try `^\d+,("[a-z]+|[a-z0-9,]+"),(?=(?:[^"\n]|"[^"\n]*")*$)`, see https://regex101.com/r/vWIFwW/1